# How can I hide command prompt in a VB program but also take an action?

Tags: vb.net, formatting, format, command-prompt

I am creating a program that will format flash drives selected by the user. I am doing this by using the `format.com` process. The issue with hiding the command prompt window is command prompt requires you to hit enter in order to begin the format of the drive. Is there a way to bypass this? Also, is there anyway VB can tell when command prompt has finished so I can create a message that says the formatting is finished? My relevant code is below.

```
For j = 0 To drives.Length() - 1
            Dim formatProcess As New ProcessStartInfo("format.com", drives(j) & "/Q /FS:NTFS /V:" & formattedDate)
            formatProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            formatProcess.CreateNoWindow = True
            Process.Start(formatProcess)
        Next
```

Comment: Try utilizing [WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to wait until the process has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of hiding it, you can force a press of the enter key immediately (and then possibly hide it).

You can do this:

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
```

As for sensing when it is done:

Is there a process that shows up while it is formatting? If so, you can check for this process and display the message when the process isn't there.

Comment: Is there a good way to delay this? The enter key seems to be interacting with my actual program so two command prompts open as the "Format" button is being selected. This seems to be because command prompt hasn't fully opened before the enter key is sent.

Comment: The best way would be to wait until the command process has started. But a cheap way would just be to do `Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` (which in this case waits 2000 ms = 2s)

Comment: @user3517647 Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes it does. I only had a short day at work today but I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know how it goes.